# How Do I Format And Entire Column Base On One Cell Value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to format cells in an entire column if they include the date from another cell.

Here is what I have so far:

Formula *=P4* applies to *'Sheet'!$E:$E*

(P4 cell contains the date... which is in a date format ---> *3/29/18*)

I'm using *Use a formula to determine what cells to format*.

Cells E1 and E2 end up getting formatted... however, E2 is the only date match out of those 2 cells (E1 is header cell). None of the other cells that match P4 (contain *3/29/18*) in the E column are getting formatted.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make P4 absolute:

```
=$E1 = $P$4
```

Comment: Thank you! However, now the entire column is highlighted/formatted... The cell that I'm referencing ($P$4) has date formatting... Could that be causing the problem?